# Are there IAR C-SPY macro debugging command as GHS MULTI does, such as "Step In" ,"Step Out" and "Halt"

Tags: c, iar, greenhills

I would like to make IAR C-SPY macro debug, but I can't, because their debugging guide as User Manual don't say what they provide.
GHS MULTI is very kindly good manual because they say what they can and all their command are described.
I would like to make use of IAR C-SPY commands as GHS does such as "halt" and "si"(Step In).
Is anyone knows how they can do that?

Comment: google "IAR C-SPY" brought this: [Debugging the application](http://supp.iar.com/FilesPublic/UPDINFO/005691/arm/doc/infocenter/tutor_debugging.ENU.html). Isn't this what you are looking for?

Comment: No, it's not. I seek just the command of macro that is manipulated without toolbar.

Comment: The correct link for command-line macro debugging for ARM http://www.iarsys.co.jp/download/LMS2/arm/7802/ewarm7802doc/arm/doc/EWARM_DebuggingGuide.ENU.pdf and tutorial https://www.iar.com/support/resources/articles/introduction-to-debugging-with-c-spy-macros/